Replacing the Cordova Splash screen Icon
I know this question has been asked many times, most posts are from a few years ago and I've read all the posts and tried the offered solutions to no avail.
It seems, when I run 'cordova run android' or 'cordova build android' a fresh, new ic_cdv_splashscreen.xml is generated in the folder platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable
It seems that this is the file that displays the cordova logo on the splash screen, even if I already placed my splash screen images in the correct folders under platforms/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/drawable-*  (where * is replaced by hdpi and so on)
What happens:
I run 'cordova run android'
cordova then rebuilds the app, and generates the ic_cdv_splashscreen.xml
in my emulator, the app starts up
the splash screen shows, with the cordova logo, for a few seconds
on the splash screen, the cordova logo is replaced by my proper logo
splash screen fades after the set time
I have searched long and wide and pulled a lot of hairs.
How do I get rid of the cordova logo?
[Edit]
I have temporarily fixed / hacked the issue by adding the following preference to my to my config.xml
<preference name="AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon" value="res/icons/splash_screen.png" />

The image used is 180px x 180px with a round icon centered in a 120px radius.
Still, my question stands: what is the proper way to do this?

So what's issue? AndroidWindowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon is not a hack or a temp fix, it's just proper way to set the splash icon.

Right, silly me, it seems I misunderstood this.

It seems my 'hack' in my original post is the actual answer.
